# Android Parse query from local data store too slow

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, saving-data

In my main activity, I'm filling a recyclerview with an array of strings; however, I'm getting those strings from my parse database.

I now know that when you query for information the method is asynchronous meaning it runs in the background waiting to receive a response from the database while your code continues to run. I ran into the problem that it took too long to fill an array with the strings and the recycerview was already filled (with null values because the array hadn't been filled yet)

So I decided save to the data locally with parse and use the database to back up the information. My problem is still that this too is way too slow to fill my adapter for the recyclerview. I even made sure that it wasn't querying the database and turned of my data and internet connection to the phone I was testing it on. It was the same story.

Does anyone know an optimized way to retrieve data so it's fast enough to fill the recyclerview because right now it takes like a full 3 seconds to get the strings. I do not want to pause my program for 3 seconds just to wait for parse to do it's thing.

Here is how I save the data.

```
// get current user
ParseObject studentClasses = new ParseObject("StudentClasses");

// register their periods into database
studentClasses.put("student_id", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
studentClasses.put("first_period", ClassSelected_Period[PERIOD1]);
studentClasses.put("second_period", ClassSelected_Period[PERIOD2]);
studentClasses.put("third_period", ClassSelected_Period[PERIOD3]);
studentClasses.put("fourth_period", ClassSelected_Period[PERIOD4]);
studentClasses.put("fifth_period", ClassSelected_Period[PERIOD5]);
studentClasses.put("sixth_period", ClassSelected_Period[PERIOD6]);
studentClasses.put("seventh_period", ClassSelected_Period[PERIOD7]);

// save the information locally and in database
studentClasses.pinInBackground();

// navigate user home
navigateToHome();
```

Here is how I retrieve the data in my main activity

```
// query database for user's classes
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("StudentClasses");
query.fromLocalDatastore().whereEqualTo("student_id", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

// find it, first looking at local data store then going to database
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>()
{
    @Override
    public void done (ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e)
    {
        if (e == null)
        {
            // retrieved the object
            userClasses[PERIOD1] = parseObject.getString("first_period");
            userClasses[PERIOD2] = parseObject.getString("second_period");
            userClasses[PERIOD3] = parseObject.getString("third_period");
            userClasses[PERIOD4] = parseObject.getString("fourth_period");
            userClasses[PERIOD5] = parseObject.getString("fifth_period");
            userClasses[PERIOD6] = parseObject.getString("sixth_period");
            userClasses[PERIOD7] = parseObject.getString("seventh_period");

            // DEBUG: shows how long it takes for method to return
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"during call = " + userClasses[PERIOD1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            // DEBUG: shows if exception happened
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exception Thrown" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});

// DEBUG: shows how long it takes for code to reach this point
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"after call = " + userClasses[PERIOD1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The toast "after call =" shows pretty much as soon as the screen appears and it says "after call = null"

the toast "during call =" shows up about 3 seconds later and say "during call = English" (which is what it should say)

Even if it's not using parse to save it, I'll be fine with it. I can always use parse to just back it up or perhaps I'm just doing something wrong and there's a way better way.

If you are interested, here is my entire main activity

```
    package maxbleggi.afstudentplanner;

import ... 

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    // "MACROS" for user's class periods
    private final int PERIOD1 = 0;
    private final int PERIOD2 = 1;
    private final int PERIOD3 = 2;
    private final int PERIOD4 = 3;
    private final int PERIOD5 = 4;
    private final int PERIOD6 = 5;
    private final int PERIOD7 = 6;

    // toolbar
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    // navigation drawer
    private DrawerLayout navDrawer;

    // user's data
     public String[] userClasses = new String[10];

    // list to fill Classroom class with
    private List<ClassroomClass> classrooms;

    /*
    * on creation of activity
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // initialise and set toolbar as actionbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // initialize nav bars
        initNavBars();

        // initialize drawer layout
        NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        // initialize nav drawer
        navDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        initNavDrawer(navDrawer);

        // initialize layout manager for recycler view
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mainLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        // initialize data for all classes before setting adapter
        initClassData();

        // set the adapter for recycler view
        RecyclerView.Adapter mainAdapter = new MainRecyclerAdapter(classrooms);

        // initialize recycler view elements
        RecyclerView mainRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_view);

        // add layout manager to recycler view
        mainRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mainLayoutManager);

        // add adapter to recycler view
        mainRecyclerView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
    }

    /*
    * initializes the class data for each class
    */
    public void initClassData()
    {
        // check if a user is not cached
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser == null)
        {
            // prompt user to Register screen
            // create intent to start activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // start new activity
            startActivity(intent);

            // stop current activity
            finish();
        }

        // query database for user's classes
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("StudentClasses");
        query.fromLocalDatastore().whereEqualTo("student_id", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

        // find it, first looking at local data store then going to database
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>()
        {
            @Override
            public void done (ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e)
            {
                if (e == null)
                {
                    // retrieved the object
                    userClasses[PERIOD1] = parseObject.getString("first_period");
                    userClasses[PERIOD2] = parseObject.getString("second_period");
                    userClasses[PERIOD3] = parseObject.getString("third_period");
                    userClasses[PERIOD4] = parseObject.getString("fourth_period");
                    userClasses[PERIOD5] = parseObject.getString("fifth_period");
                    userClasses[PERIOD6] = parseObject.getString("sixth_period");
                    userClasses[PERIOD7] = parseObject.getString("seventh_period");

                    // DEBUG: shows how long it takes for method to return
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"during call = " + userClasses[PERIOD1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    // DEBUG: shows if exception happened
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exception Thrown" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        // DEBUG: shows how long it takes for code to reach this point
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"after call = " + userClasses[PERIOD1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // fill all fields for class periods
        classrooms = new ArrayList<>();

        // titles of classes to add to list
        String[] classTitles = {"First Period", "Second Period", "Third Period", "Fourth Period",
                "Fifth Period", "Sixth Period", "Seventh Period"};

            // iterate over every period to add it to the list
            for (int i = 0; i <= PERIOD7; i++)
            {
                // if there was a class registered for that period
                if (userClasses[PERIOD3] != null)
                {
                    // add it to the class to be added to recycler view
                    classrooms.add(new ClassroomClass(userClasses[i], classTitles[i], i + 1));
                }
            }

    }

    /*
    * initialize navigation drawer
     */
    public void initNavDrawer(final DrawerLayout navDrawer)
    {
        final NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
            {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                navDrawer.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    /*
    * initialize navigation bars to allow navigation to nav drawer
    */
    private void initNavBars()
    {
       if (toolbar != null)
       {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_white);
            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    navDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            });
       }
    }
}
```

Any optimizations or fixes to any parts are appreciated thanks!

Comment: Are you running the parse query on the same thread? If you are create a new thread for the query, and mutex lock the recyler so that the the Android OS can't access it until Parse has downloaded the data. The additional thread should speed up the interaction.

Comment: Sorry but I'm used to C. I've just transitioned to Java a couple months ago. So I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Check out this link: http://www.fromdev.com/2008/05/java-threading-questions.html   The idea behind threading is to split your UI and other processor intensive tasks into seperate processes, taking advantage of all the cores. In C, the OS often handles this, or fork() does also. Threading is Java's version of fork()

Comment: After looking into it more, when you call get first in background it runs "in a different background thread. "

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It may not be the most elegant or efficient but at least it works.

Instead of using parse as the main source to save the data, use it as a backup to check the data you have stored internally. So save the data normally with parse then save your data type using shared preferences which saves the data internally.
In my case it looks like this

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(RegisterActivity.this).edit().putString("my_title", myCustomString).commit();
```

Where RegisterActivity.this is your context, my_title is the unique id for your string, and myCustomString is the custom string you want to save

All you have to do is use that one line to save the variable you want.

When you want to retrieve the data just put this line

```
myNewString = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this).getString("my_title", "defaultStringIfNothingFound");
```

Where myNewString is the new string that you save it into, MainActivity.this is the context, my_title is still the title, and defaultString.... well that one's obvious.

You can still maintain the database checking too. Just set the the saving shared preference line equal to whatever your `parseObject.getString("StringName");` equals

Now you have a quick, local cache to save and retrieve data and a redundant database to regularly update the local cache